# Increase git timeout from jenkins pipeline syntax

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm getting these messages each time my pipeline syntax command executes on downloading another repo:

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin

Receiving objects:  77% (6819/8789), 239.50 MiB | 418.00 KiB/s
Killed by signal 15.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I already tried these two jenkins-auto-generated pipeline syntax, however still fails to completely download the repo

```
git credentialsId: 'user-key', url: 'ssh://git@enterprise-bitbucket.mycompany.net:8000/poject/job.git'

git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'user-key', poll: false, url: 'ssh://git@enterprise-bitbucket.mycompany.net:8000/poject/job.git'
```

I'm thinking to test and increase the default timeout from 10 minutes to 30 however there is no option from jenkins pipeline syntax to add it.

[image]

Any suggestions on how can I increase the timeout value here? Thanks in advance

Comment: hi there, what is your ssh config? Isn't that timeout defined there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not on the ssh config of the os that is needed to change. Although I somewhat fixed this by updating our jenkins pipeline syntax:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: 'master']],
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
    extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], [$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: true, timeout: 240]],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'user-key', url: 'ssh://git@enterprise-bitbucket.mycompany.net:8000/poject/job.git']]
])
```

for much higher timeout I set it to 240 *(where I saw elsewhere from others settings via google search)*

:-)